# How to pass nginx proxy url for socket

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, proxy, socket.io

I am using socket in my application,i want to pass socket connection url from nginx as proxy url.I am doing it like that

My socket code

```
var socket = io.connect('/explorer/socket',{
      'reconnect': true,
      'reconnection delay': 500
    });
```

My nginx conf

```
location /explorer/socket {
                proxy_pass    http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000;
        }
```

but it is not working,it is connecting to my localhost,but i want to connect with my proxy url which i have defined in nginx. so how can i pass proxy url inside io.connect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to change in nginx configuartion like that

```
location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_pass    http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000;
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
proxy_http_version 1.1;

proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
proxy_read_timeout 86400;

access_log off;
error_log /opt/nginx/logs/websockets.error.log;


        }
```

1) /socket.io/ - this will tell nginx to pass your socket call to that given ip

Now change in your socket code

```
var socket = io.connect('/',{
      'reconnect': true,
      'reconnection delay': 500
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your nginx.conf's location as below;

```
location /explorer/socket {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:3000;
}
```

Source: http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-nodejs-websockets-socketio/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,But how to access it in the socket code i mean inside  var socket = io.connect('/explorer/socket',{
      'reconnect': true,
      'reconnection delay': 500
    });

Comment: I didn't understand what you'd like to access exactly?

Comment: I want to make socket connection in my program like  io.connect('http://localhost:3000'),but i want there,i will pass this url from nginx called proxy url,so how could i pass it,i didn't want to mention localhost:8080 in my program,it should be from nginx